# geoJson : Json.load() ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 9

Tags: python, json, django, geojson

I have trouble loading my `json` file using the `json.load()`. My format is a `geojson` with the following example format:

```
    { "type" : "Feature Collection",
      {"features" : [
            { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : "FORT_1",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["121.046859", "14.54544278"]},
        "properties" : { "name" : "City"}
         },
            { "type" : "Feature",
        "id" : "FORT_2",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : ["121.0500991", "14.54973692"]},
        "properties" : { "name" : "One"}
         },
```

I wanted to test it out using the following code, knowing that this will create a `dict`:

```
            with open(geojsonFilePath) as file:
            jsonFile = json.load(file)

            for feature in jsonFile['features']:
                print (['id'])
                print (['geometry'],['type'])
                print (['geometry'],['coordinates'])
                print (['properties'],['name'])
```

However the error occurs at the line `jsonFile = json.load(file)`

Comment: What are `FORT_1` and `FORT_2`? Your json is invalid with those

Comment: @MosesKoledoye hangon let me check that on my template and retry. although the error points out @  the line where `{"features" : {` is placed.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye anyways I rechecked it had the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all the issues with your JSON I could find

Firstly, at

```
{ "type" : "Feature Collection",
   {"features" : [
```

You're adding an object without a key, it should be either

```
{ "type" : "Feature Collection",
  "features" : [
```

or

```
{ "type" : "Feature Collection",
  "somekey": features" : [
```

Then, there's `FORT_1` and `FORT_2`, which look like they are variable names or constants, so this should be either enclosed in quotes, or the values of those variables/constant needs to be substituted.

Finally, there are many mismatched braces, not sure if you have shared a snippet or the whole json, but the array brace of features is not closed and subsequent braces aren't closed.

I've corrected your input making a few assumptions for reference.

```
 {
    "type": "Feature Collection",

    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FORT_1",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": ["121.046859", "14.54544278"]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "City"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FORT_2",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": ["121.0500991", "14.54973692"]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "One"
        }
    }]

 }
```

Comment: hello sir thank you for clearly pointing out my error at that line. I fixed it and just had a delimiter error now. :) thank you!

Comment: I'd just like to ask, is it still valid if my json say perhaps end like this : `{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FORT_2",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": ["121.0500991", "14.54973692"]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "One"
        }
    },]
 }`

Comment: where a comma still appears right before the 2nd symbol? It's just because I'm using a template right now and had that delimiter problem after fixing this error. I'm wondering if this is the cause?

Comment: oh nevermind i just found an online geojson checker and it is indeed a problem. thanks!